java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown file: META-INF/androidx.emoji2_emoji2.version
Getting below error while running the android project in case of  compileSdk = 35 and       targetSdk = 35.
Exception is :
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown file: META-INF/androidx.emoji2_emoji2.version
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:601)

This is caused by a version incompatibility.
I fixed it by adding an explicit dependency to compose foundation in my Android Application dependency.
I'm using the compose plugin (org.jetbrains.compose), so I just had to do this:
implementation(compose.foundation)

Use whatever method you use to add the foundation dependency manually.
You might need to add more dependencies I have these related to compose:
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime)
implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)    
implementation(compose.ui)
implementation(compose.foundation)
implementation(compose.material3)
implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)


This is what brought me in this direction it might help you investigate if this doesn't solve it for you.
Launch gradle with the dependencies task, you can do so inside android studio gradle tab or via command line:
./gradlew app:dependencies

look for the emoji2 dependency (androidx.emoji2:emoji2). For me I could see the dependency was brought in indirectly by androidx.compose.ui:ui through androidx.activity:activity increasing it from version 1.2.0 to version 1.3.0
I noticed some compose library was being upgraded to higher versions than the foundation library and so I tried to explicitly add the dependency.
